# How to navigate 'logical' lines individually in vim?

Tags: vim

I know that there is a setting for this in `vim`, I just can't find it now...

Basically, I like `set wrap`. I like it alot. I'm less fond of it skipping down to each actual line, rather than the more intuitive next displayed line. For instance, say I have the following file:

```
1 Some really, really, really long line that I really possibly should have
  but I do have it, so I'm stuck with it, and if my cursor is ->| here
  and then I press the down button, much to my dismay,
2 The cursor ends up here! ->|
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can type `gj` to move down one screen line, as opposed to one logical line with `j`.

It may also be possible to map `gj` to `j`.
Here's an article you may find useful for that:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_by_screen_lines_instead_of_file_lines