# vim navigation by linebreaks with wrap on

Tags: vim, keyboard-navigation

How can I navigate by line breaks rather than by hard breaks when wrap is turned on, so that when I go down a line I actually go down the line I see rather than the source line in the file? This would be really useful when editing really long lines, such as what come out when I am editing TeX files.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/42496/how-to-navigate-logical-lines-individually-in-vim?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the default behaviour of `j` and `k` adding the following lines to your `.vimrc` file:

```
nmap <silent> j gj
nmap <silent> k gk
```

See also [vim tip 308](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_through_wrapped_lines)

Answer (score 3):

`gj` and `gk` move down and up by ‘display lines’ instead of ‘logical lines’.